# Return Json or something pretty from tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, json, api, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm using the tensorflow object detection API and I would like to know if in all the python scripts there is one that would return which labels are present in the image. Like returning a Json or something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no python script that directly generates JSON, but there is a Jupyter notebook that demonstrates how to do inference:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

Alternatively if you want to use a pre-existing script, this Jupyter notebook shows how to use a script that generates TFRecord files:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/oid_inference_and_evaluation.md

Which can then be processed using code in the `tf_example_decoder.py` as a reference:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py

Comment: But that one is not a json script, rather some thing quite dense and I have no idea how to inrepret

Answer (score 0):

https://lijiancheng0614.github.io/2017/08/22/2017_08_22_TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API/

This is what you are looking for. The last code snippet.